# How to host asp.net core sub application in different server IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I have a site named Site A (ASP.NET MVC) hosted in IIS. Now I need to host a subsite B (ASP.NET Core) as a sub application of Site A.

So url would be like

1. www.domain.com   - site A url
2. www.domain.com/siteb  - site B url

Notice that both site have same domain.

I am able to achieve this by Hosting site B as sub application of Site A in IIS.

What I need is instead of hosting Site B as sub application in IIS I need to host  site B in separate server. But still I want to make end user feel that it is part of A. That is above url scheme should be maintained and it should be hosted as individual application. I don't want to use a subdomain.  How it can be achieved any guidance please?

Comment: Reverse proxy would allow doing this

Comment: A really simple solution would be to use another sub, e.g. `www2.domain.com/siteB`. Or you could do `siteA.domain.com` and `siteB.domain.com`. And as you use the same domain, no one will really see it in any other way than they are a part of one another.

Comment: Another benefit is you don't need to add `/siteB` all the time for those url's, you can instead use simpler, shorter one's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host multiple .NET Core apps under same url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348511/how-to-host-multiple-net-core-apps-under-same-url)