# ASP .Core MVC configure application root url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have two ASP .Core MVC applications that are hosted under the same url.
I've managed to separate them with Nginx so that a certain path goes to `app-2`, while the rest goes to `app-1`:
`http://host` -> `app-1`
`http://host/setup` -> `app-2`

My problem comes when the user connects to `app-2`, as the application still thinks it's app-root is `http://host`.
This leads to the client encountering a 404 when for example style sheets are downloaded, since `app-2.css` exists under `http://host/setup/css` but the application searches in `http://host/css`.

The "include"-lines in the `.cshtml` file in `app-2` look like this:

```cs
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/css/app-2.css")" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Is there some way of "overriding" or telling `app-2` that `~` should refer to `<host>/setup/css/` instead of `<host>/css/`?
I really don't want to hardcode it in case the url changes at some point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to host multiple .NET Core apps under the same URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42348511/how-to-host-multiple-net-core-apps-under-the-same-url)

Comment: Not quite; my routing between the web apps works, but they both think their webroot is the same. I am able to successfully connect to `app-2`, but it fails to download `app-2.css` since it believes it exists under `<url>/css` instead of `<url>/config/css`.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of searching I found no way of altering the application root for the entire webserver.
What I ended up doing instead was create class `PathHelper` with options and added it to `Startup.cs`:

```cs
class PathHelper
{
    public PathHelper(IOptions<PathHelperOptions> opt)
    {
        Path = opt.Path;
        
        if (Path.StartsWith('/'))
        {
            Path = Path[1..];
        }
        if (!Path.EndsWith('/'))
        {
            Path = Path + '/';
        }
    }

    public string Path { get; }
}

class PathHelperOptions
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

# Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services
      .AddScoped<PathHelper>()
      .Configure<PathHelperOptions>(opt =>
      {
          opt.Path = this.configuration.GetSection("URL_SUFFIX");
      });

  [...]
}
```

I then used it in the `.cshtml` files like this:

```cs
@inject PathHelper helper
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content(helper.Path + "css/app-2.css")" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to include the `base` tag in pages coming from 'app-2'.

Try it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="http://host/setup">
    </head>
```

Now your relative links are sent to 'app-2'.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. Adding `<base href="http://host/setup">` to the top of the header still results in the files being loaded from `host`. Example: favicon with `href="favicon.ico"`  is loaded from `http://host/favicon.ico`.

Comment: Try adding a slash (`/`) in front: `href="/favicon.ico"`

Comment: Hmm, no. I've also tested hardcoding `base` to `http://localhost/setup` and setting favicon to `href="/favicon.ico"`, but the icon is still loaded from `localhost/favicon.ico`.